# Raspberry Pi не запускается

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

При включении raspberry выходит ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю что делать

Comment: А где ошибка-то?

Comment: Ну это не совсем ошибка, но всё же рабочий стол почему то не появляется, только этот текст, можно ли как то это исправить?

Comment: Вы точно нормальную систему Raspbian ставили, а не какую-нибудь лайт без графического стола? Поскольку по ощущениям это нормальный старт системы без графического стола.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ошибка, а консоль=) - добро пожаловать в мир Линукс.
Скорее всего Вы скачали Lite версию, в которой нету рабочего стола.
Скачайте стандартную версию с сайта, и распакуйте на карту-памяти или же просто введите команды: `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg xinit` затем `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods` и наконец `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
После чего, введите reboot, для перезагрузки. Система запустится с рабочим столом.

Comment: Не совсем, я скачал как раз ту версию, она запускалась, все было нормально, но в один момент бац и эта надпись, а консоль там никакущая, при вводе цифр они отображаются, а при вводе символов они отображаются квадратиками

Comment: Потому-что стоит русская раскладка, а терминал её не отображает, это лечится запуском команды: sudo raspi-config, там в каком-то пункте включается загрузка в режиме "Рабочего стола"

Comment: А как поставить английскую раскладку? Я жму alt+shift и ничего... Я знаю, что возможно там другая комбинация клавиш

Comment: Так как? Если знаешь прошу ответь, как поменять раскладку клавиатуры в этом терминале (alt + shift уже пробовал)

Comment: Просто попробуй перезалить новый образ на флешку, это должно решить твою проблему, желательно другую версию.